# PPP over SSH - is this correct?

Tags: encryption, linux, ssh, vpn

I see a lot of talk online about whipping up a VPN connection using `PPP` over `SSH`. This term confuses me, as `SSH` is an app tier protocol and `PPP` operates on the data-link layer.

So, my question is: Shouldn't it technically be `SSH` over `PPP`, and not `PPP` over `SSH`?

Comment: Not if you initiate an SSH connection then tunnel PPP through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is correct, you are putting PPP packets into your SSH connection. The idea of a VPN is that you are tunnelling, which basically means that you have an SSH connection (a tunnel) that looks like PPP when you are sending something into it. Thus, if you send a request through your tunnel with a protocol like HTTPS, your packet on the wire will look something like this:

Ethernet( IP( TCP( SSH( PPP( IP( TCP( TLS( HTTP( your packet payload)))))))))

Tunnelling itself is not a security thing; another common use of tunnelling is 4to6 routers, which allow you to tunnel IPv6 traffic over an IPv4 network. Similarly, you can use a SOCKS proxy to forward web requests over SSH to make it look like your requests are coming from somewhere else.

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thank you for the answer.